# VisualForce Programming does not yield the output

Tags: java, salesforce, visualforce

I am new to the `SalesForce` and working in the `VisualForce`. I developed below code and looks like its not giving correct output. Could you please guide me whats going wrong here? I dont see any pointers after spending two days. Please guide.

```
<apex:page standardController="account" recordSetVar="arecs">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="List of Accounts">
            <!-- This works as loop -->
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!arecs}" var="item">
                <apex:column value="{!item.id}" />
                <apex:column value="{!item.name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!item.createddate}" />
                <apex:column value="{!item.Phone}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!arecs}" var="rec">
                <apex:column value="{!rec.Industry}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!rec.Type}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!rec.Rating}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

**The result of the program I am getting:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons that caused this issue. Lest rule out one issue at a time.

The Standard Set Controller that you are using `standardController="account" recordSetVar="arecs"` will use currently **active List View** to filter the records.
On Accounts tab select a list view that shows some records and then try reloading this visualforcee page.
(Select the list view and hit `Go!`)

Comment: Thanks for inputs, but I dont quite followed you. Could you please tell exactly where I need to change?

Comment: Are you using a system administrator profile? What are the Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults for Account object? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Answer (score 1):

I hope the profile using which you're running your code has access to `Account` object. Otherwise there is nothing wrong with your code. I would suggest you to try again. Below is your code which I tried on my **Dev Org**:

```
<apex:page standardController="account" recordSetVar="arecs">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="List of Accounts">
            <!-- This works as loop -->
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!arecs}" var="item">
                <apex:column value="{!item.id}" />
                <apex:column value="{!item.name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!item.createddate}" />
                <apex:column value="{!item.Phone}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!arecs}" var="rec">
                <apex:column value="{!rec.Industry}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!rec.Type}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!rec.Rating}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

And below is the output of your code:

[image]

Comment: No, I am using Prod. Not sure what had happen. I deleted all accounts and created it newly, which worked. But certainly need to identify why it happened. Root cause is must here.